# How can I get the Highscore to Update and Stay the same until beaten

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[Google Drive of Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GwWE42RvnlJr-85N520fMvv0qNzAn_W1/view?usp=sharing)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static GameControl instance;         //A reference to our game control script so we can access it statically.
    public Text scoreText;                      //A reference to the UI text component that displays the player's score.
    public Text highscoreText;                  //A reference to the UI text component that displays the player's highscore.
    public GameObject gameOvertext;             //A reference to the object that displays the text which appears when the player dies.

    private int highScore = 0;                  //The games highscore
    private int score = 0;                      //The player's score.
    public bool gameOver = false;               //Is the game over?
    public float scrollSpeed = -1.5f;

    void Start()
    {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
        highscoreText.text = "HighScore: " + highScore.ToString();
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        //If we don't currently have a game control set this one to be it otherwise destroy this one
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if(instance != this)
            Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //If the game is over and the player has pressed some input
        if (gameOver && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            //reload the current scene.
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }


    }

    public void BirdScored()
    {
            //The bird can't score if the game is over.
            if (gameOver)
                return;

            //If the game is not over, increase the score and set highscore
            score++;

            //adjust the score text.
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();

            // Check if this score beats the highscore
            //if (score > highScore)
            //{
            //    highScore = score;
            //    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", highScore);
            //}
            //highscoreText.text = "HighScore: " + highScore.ToString();

    }

    public void BirdDied()
    {

            //Activate the game over text.
            gameOvertext.SetActive(true);
            //The game is over.
            gameOver = true;

        // Check if this score beats the highscore
        if (score > highScore)
        {
            highScore = score;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", highScore);
        }
            highscoreText.text = "HighScore: " + highScore.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am looking to get a highscore to display, and update when the player dies. The base score is working correctly, but I can't get the highscore to update. If someone could please help me with this it would be much appreciated. If you need to see other code, let me know what you think and hot to go about it.

Comment: Looking at the code, you have commented out the if(score > highScore)-segment.. Why?

Comment: Because that wasn't changing anything

Comment: It would have changed the highscore :) However, you changed thehighscore text before you changed the highscore, had you dont it the other way around on the other hand :)

Comment: I am so confused by this...

Answer (score 0):

Doing something along these lines should work perfectly.

```
public void BirdDied()
{
    //Activate the game over text.
    gameOvertext.SetActive(true);
    //The game is over.
    gameOver = true;

    // Check if this score beats the highscore
    if (score > highScore)
    {
        highScore = score;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", highScore);
    }

    highscoreText.text = "HighScore: " + highScore.ToString();
}
```

Also be sure to get the highscore and update the highScoreText when you start the game

```
void Start()
{
    highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
    highscoreText.text = "HighScore: " + highScore.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Updated answer

**EDIT**
After looking at your project, i notice the HighscoreText is not set in the inspector, see image
[image]

Simply drag HighScoreText (located under Canvas in your Hierarchy view) to the Highscore field there in the inspector.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to use PlayerPrefs.They don't want their highscore to be carried over to the next scene and then displayed.

Comment: @Ali looking at his code, he is clearly just reloading the same scene.. So i think he does want the highscore to persist.. However this could be achived without having PlayerPrefs, PlayerPrefs are more for saving data between gaming sessions, but considering he used it in his example, i assumed thats what he wants.

Comment: Would taking out the PlayerPrefs fix it? I only want the highscore to stay the same when the character dies, unless its beaten ofcourse. Then for it to update it

Comment: So you want the highscore to update only when the game is over?

Comment: Yeah, and then stay the same until its beaten

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now it will update the highscore (if beaten) and save it to PlayerPrefs.  when BirdDied() is called. And in Start() it will read the highscore from PlayerPrefs and assign it to the highScoreText.text.

Comment: highscoreText.text = "HighScore: " + highScore.ToString();

This line keeps getting an error whenever the bird gains a point

Comment: What kind of error, NullReferenceException? Make sure the highscoreText is assigned to. And also, if you dont want the highscore to  update every time you get a point, remove the highscore-logic from BirdScored :)

Comment: highScoreText doesnt have a value, it doesnt have any text-object assigned to it, thats why you are getting a NullReferenceException. Seeing as how scoreText is not throwing a NullReferenceException, maybe you forgot to assign a text-object to the HighScoreText-field in the inspector view in Unity? Check out how you got scoreText to work, and do the same for highscoretext :)

Comment: Updated the code to what I have now, The highscore on screen is always displaying 0, never changes

Comment: I think you updated the Question with the code from another class?

Comment: Fixed haha, sorry

Comment: Anything? at all?

Comment: Looking at the code in the question, i see no obviously problems. It should work as far as i can see.. You could try adding some logging and try to figure out what step is causting the problem. Like in start you could add a Debug.Log("highscore read from playerprefs: " + highScore) just to verify what you get from there. And in birddied you could add a line to verify that it actually updates the highscore value.. Just to get a sense of where something might be going wrong.

Comment: If you want to post a .zip of the project i could take a look at it i guess.

Comment: I have edited the original post with a hyperlink to my googledrive for the project

Comment: That did it... why is it always the little things

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your Game-State logic from your Out-Of-Game State logic.

For example, one of my projects has [a static<sup>1</sup> class](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/statistics/StatisticsTracker.cs#L14) to hold all of the statistics<sup>2</sup> I'm interested in without being reliant on a MonoBehaviour component. This statistics class also handles the serialization and deserialization for the statistics, although it doesn't have to.

I also created a special [`HighScore` class](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/statistics/StatHighscore.cs) to handle dealing with values that can be reset, but that I still want to know what the "best" value ever stored was.

Not going to say that my code is the best, just these are the principles you need to follow.

1 <sub>Static fields also let me access these properties from anywhere.</sub>
2 <sub>All of these are still *game-state* values for this particular project, but they will still persist if I were to change scenes</sub>

Comment: `public static class Statistics { public static int HighScore; public static int score; }`

Comment: And where would this go? Just a new class altogether? Also what code will go in it?

Comment: New class, yes. And whatever code you think you need. In my case, that included serialization (saving/loading) and other methods, like resetting all statistics that need to be reset.